# Insert tabs in INSERT mode when expandtab is set

Tags: insert-mode, tab-characters

I have set `expandtab` in my `.vimrc` file to convert `tab` to multiple `space` characters. However some files (like Makefile) need actual the `tab` character inserted.

Is there an easy way to force the insertion the `tab` while I am typing?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Instead of just pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, first press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This can be used to insert a variety of special chars. See `:help i_CTRL-V` for details.

<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> also works in command-line mode (`:help c-CTRL-V`), and even in some other programs entirely. (e.g. bash, mutt.)

If you have <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> mapped to something else, try <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd>. This has the same effect in Vim as <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>, but some terminals use it for control flow, in which case Vim won't ever see it.

Comment: Or `<c-v>009` in case of broken Tab key or hardcore ASCII purist :-)

Answer (score 25):

Rather than change your behavior (which is error prone).
I would set up vim to behave differently for this file type.

So in my normal editing I expand tabs. But specifically for `make` files I set the `noexpandtab` so that tabs are retained.

Add the following to your ~/.vimrc file:

```
" Normal action
set expandtab

if has("autocmd")

    " If the filetype is Makefile then we need to use tabs
    " So do not expand tabs into space.
    autocmd FileType make   set noexpandtab

endif
```

Comment: I answered his question, but you've actually figured out what the underlying problem is way better than I did. Goodjob.

Comment: I think both answers are valuable. Because sometimes you're logged in somewhere remote and don't want to mess with the vim config but just quickly want to edit a Makefile.